# PDF tollbar without download button

Tags: html, pdf, iframe

Is there a way to have an iFrame with full toolbar except for the download button.

On the web I found this solution

```
<iframe src="URL#toolbar=0" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
```

But as u know it removes completely the toolbar and I would love to actually keep it.

Basically:
this is how is [normally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChTUv.png) and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEXKk.png) is I would love to have it (or something similar).
I already know i cannot prevent ppl to download it in other way, but I'm only interest in this graphic difference

Thanks to anyone who could help me

---

Also I noticed that mozilla doesnt view iFrame, is there a way to allowed it or something similar?
I need something that ppl can use without changing configuration on their personal mozilla

---

The look that I'm looking for (asked by my boss) -> [image: toolbar]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mozilla browsers have no problem with Iframe, but browsers are configured by users to their security preferences.

```
<iframe id="page2" height="50%" width="100%"src="http://africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf#page=2"></iframe>
<iframe id="page1" height="50%" width="100%"src="http://africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf#page=1"></iframe>
```

Same as the web page text and images, Audio or Video content, ***all*** pdfs are "Download first to view" does not matter if

- A=Href
- Embed
- Iframe
- Object (avoid as depreciated)
- cUrl (Users direct get)

So why remove the button if its not showing in the frame due to any ad blocker or other user setting such as send downloads into external secured PDF viewer

Mozilla browser with pdf plugin or add-in or PDF extender same as Chrome/Edge

[image]

FireFox with a frame blocker active for the same page 3 blocked items.

[image]

If you wish to change the Iframe view you need to be the PDF viewer application, but there is no guarantee it is the one the user is viewing within.

[image]

Here is a demo of a browser viewer where **the download and print buttons are removed.** However Browsers need to allow the user to control their own view so I have also opened the download on the right in a companion viewer.
A PDF client cannot view a PDF unless it is ***Decrypted after a download*** thus their copy is available for view and edit.

[image]

Comment: I thought Mozilla has problem with iFrame because first my mozilla doesnt let me view my iFrame and I read online that other ppl where having problem with it and has other ppl telling them it was a general problem; but if u say so I'm gonna look deeper

Comment: And for asking why remove the button it's because my boss saw on a portal that u can create a pdf view without that option (I'm gonna post the picture he sent me the other day as example for what he wants)

Comment: Oh okay. thnks       
And for the last shot it makes sense now, for the googleDocs view. My question now is: can I do something similar, but with PDF loaded in a database? (I'm using XAMPP with phpMyAdmin)

Comment: I was hoping u wouldnt say pdf.js; it's since yesterday that I'm having troblue understand how to use it

Comment: MMM i'm gonna discuss with him. Thanks you for your time. I'm also gonna retry with pdf.js and the one you linked me